# Getting a error Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so while trying to execute netbeans in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu-20.04

Hey I am trying to execute Netbeans 12.4 on ubuntu 20.04.1 and getting this error
my java version is openjdk 16.0.1 can anybody help me to fix this error ?

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-16-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2387)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:746)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:310)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2392)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:808)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:61)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:58)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.PlatformGraphicsInfo.createGE(PlatformGraphicsInfo.java:36)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:93)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE.<clinit>(GraphicsEnvironment.java:84)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:106)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:228)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:98)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: Is it possible that you installed the headless version of the JDK package?

Comment: thanks for help now the issue is resolved.

Comment: If you've resolved it. Please provide an Answer with details on your resolution. (Even if you installed the headless version of the JDK package. Why would that cause an issue? What is a "headless" JDK package)

Answer (score 4):

**Answering this question for future users.**

I had same issue with JDK 17 because I had installed headless JDK. May this package wasn't included within headless JDK. I resolved this issue by updating my JDK using commands below. Please don't forget to replace you JDK version on command.

**sudo apt update**

**sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk**

Answer (score 0):

Setting the java.awt.headless to true, for example during static initialisation of the class, might help, depending on what you want to do:

```
    static {
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
    }
```

It helped for me. :)